# Как узнать кто занял порт и освободить его?

Tags: java, tomcat

Я запускаю tomcat и получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent :
>   java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested
>   exception is:     java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind
>   failed)

1099 порт занят а для запуска он нужен. Как понять кто занял и освободить?

Comment: возможно, tomcat уже запущен и там висит некий процес! Попробуйте принудительно остановить tomcat и заново запуститься. В какой системе поднимаете томкет?

Comment: попробуйте `sudo netstat -tulpn`, после этого можно убить процесс по PID'у через `kill`

Comment: @JVic да но в том то и дело что я остановил сервер в IDE и по идее tomcat должен был тоже остановиться и освободить порт, но этого не произошло.

Comment: остановите его с консоли принудительно! Также попробуйте `lsof -w -n -i tcp:1099` отобразит какое приложение заняло порт

Comment: @Alex Chermenin вот что получается MacBook-Pro-My:~ MyMac$ sudo netstat -tulpn
netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol

Comment: @JVic а как его из консоли остановить??

Comment: @Pavel тогда без параметра `n`. видимо под линуксом и под macOS параметры отличаются.

Comment: @Alex ChermeninMacBook-Pro-My:~ MyMac$ lsof -w -n -i tcp:1099
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    797 MyMac   22u  IPv6 0xf9bab4d2ea48cad3      0t0  TCP *:rmiregistry (LISTEN) да нашел его а как остановить? kil ...?

Comment: запустите `shutdown.sh` лежит по моему в папке `bin` томкета

Comment: либо `catalina.sh stop`, а если после этого не освободится - `kill 797`, а если и после этого никак - `kill -9 797` (797 - это PID процесса из вывода выше)

Comment: @Alex Chermenin ага понял только чуть до вашего комментария ввел kill 797 а что флаг -9 означает? (Добавьте ответ я приму все заработало спасибо большое)

Comment: `-9` - это сигнал `SIGKILL` - принудительное завершение процесса. по умолчанию `kill` отправляет `SIGTERM`, который многие программы могут обработать и правильно завершиться.

Comment: Да то торрент все порты занимает, не парьтесь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использованием скрипта `catalina.sh` с параметром `stop` не удалось завершить Tomcat и освободить порт, то можно сделать следующее:

1. Определить, какой процесс занимает порт, с помощью команды `sudo netstat -tulp`.
2. Остановить процесс с использованием команды `kill {PID}`, где `{PID}` - идентификатор процесса, занимающего порт (из вывода предыдущей команды).
3. Если предыдущая команда не смогла остановить процесс, можно использовать команду `kill -9 {PID}`, которая приведёт к принудительному завершению процесса.